# Having program exit with ctrl c

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a script which runs a number of unit tests, but when I hit control c it just exits the particular unit test, not the whole script. Is there any way I can achieve this? This is my code which actually performs the execution of the unit tests.

```
    #bitshift right to obtain correct return value, execution of each test.
    returnValue = os.system(path) >> 8
    #running total of failures in the program.
    failures += returnValue
```

This is how I call this function and exit the program.

```
failures = execTests(path, testList)
#exit program with returncode as number of failures
sys.exit(failures)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you attempted to use a try/except (obviously try blah blah blah except KeyboardInterrupt) and then either used sys.exit(failures) directly OR put in break a couple of times to get out of whatever loop you may be in and then used sys.exit(failures). Another option would be to write failures to a text file and then use sys.exit() without any arguments. Then there is the classic fix of running from the command line as admin. Alternately Python may be waiting for your test to finish; pressing CTRL + C again should close it. Of course, you could go for the less elegant option of writing output to a text file and then using os.system("taskkill ...") to exit Python altogether (don't particularly recommend this). Just a couple of thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this feature is already present in the API. Coming from the *The Python Standard Library*,[25.3. unittest — Unit testing framework](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#command-line-options) here is the relevant excerpt:

> **`-c`**, **`--catch`**
>
> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> during the test run waits for the current test to end and then reports all the results so far. A second <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> raises the normal `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.
>
> See [Signal Handling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#signal-handling) for the functions that provide this functionality.